# How to send data in between fragments Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, settings, bottomnavigationview

I have four fragments in a bottom navigation view which is initialised in the MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_simulation, R.id.navigation_news, R.id.navigation_settings)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }

}
```

I want to be able to turn a switch on or off in the settings fragment and have this effect aspects primarily within the HomeFragment and SimulationFragment, in the OnCreateView of the HomeFragment class I have created a View for the settings class so that this can be found within the HomeFragment:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Retrofit retrofitClient = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
        service = retrofitClient.create(Service.class);
        settings = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        mapView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return mapView;
    }
```

However, when for example I go from the HomeFragment (being the navigation host fragment) to the SettingsFragment, checking a Switch and then navigating back to the HomeFragment, the state appears to be lost, here is the basic idea of what I'm trying to do in the HomeFragment:

```
Switch heatmap = settings.findViewById(R.id.displayHeatmap);

            heatmap.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
                if(isChecked) {
                    addHeatMap();
                }
                else {
                    mMap.clear();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you using viewModels? If so, use a shared viewModel containing a liveData

Comment: You could also use [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Comment: @Amin Perfect, looked into this and it worked. Thanks.